# i am getting “Error generating image.” Files permission is 777 and gd library is installed (Drupal)

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I had installed gd library and also given 755 permission to the files but i am getting 500 - Internal server error on my Drupal site.

My site URL is http://vestcom.ca/dev/

One of example URL of error is http://vestcom.ca/dev/?q=sites/default/files/styles/cardealer-car-mini-thumbnail/public/property-photos/IMG_1373.JPG&itok=_DfNUQVW

If anybody have any idea about how do i debug this or how can i get image then please let me know.

Comment: I think you should check your public files folder permission. Also check if the files persist there. As i have checked http://vestcom.ca/dev/?q=sites/default/files/IMG_1373.JPG this url is taking me to the 404 page not found page.

Comment: @Anurag i think you should check again go to http://vestcom.ca/dev/ and see console

Comment: Would you please share the original uploaded file http path? Also found a link that may help you [https://www.drupal.org/node/587592]

Comment: @Anurag sorry for that because it is keep changing as i am debuging and working on that